# Integrate Robolectric and JDave

Tags: android, testing, tdd, bdd, robolectric

I would like to know if there is an easy way to have these two frameworks work together, really like the JDave BDD syntax and the Robolectric framework to do test outside android environment.

Is this possible, each have their custom TestRunner, have anyone else tried to do this? Is it doable in a simple way?